# How to add static values together without entering any values in html and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add two static values together automatically without entering any values into the textbox and display the total amount inside the third box, but it does not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txt1, #txt2').keyup(function() {
    var res = parseFloat($('#txt1').val()) || 0;
    var ser = parseFloat($('#txt2').val()) || 0;

    $('#total').val(res + ser);


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <label>Text 1<span>*</span></label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control dec" id="txt1" name="txt1" value="30">

  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <label>Text 2<span>*</span></label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control dec" id="txt2" name="txt2" value="50">

  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <label>Total<span>*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" name="txt3">

  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I fixed the snippet, please take a second to look at the diff between versions (so you can see how to include jQuery, and also note that we can't parse PHP...)

Comment: It is working. You just have it set to do the work on the `keyup` event of the fields. When did you want the total to come up?

Comment: You want to execute the add operation just after the DOM is fully loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Call function on ducument.ready and on keyup

```js
  function calc() {
    var res = parseFloat($('#txt1').val()) || 0;
    var ser = parseFloat($('#txt2').val()) || 0;

    $('#total').val(res + ser);


  }

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txt1, #txt2').keyup(calc);
  calc();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <label>Text 1<span>*</span></label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control dec" id="txt1" name="txt1" value="30">

  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <label>Text 2<span>*</span></label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control dec" id="txt2" name="txt2" value="50">

  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <label>Total<span>*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" name="txt3">

  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
```

Comment: is there any possible ways of adding the two numbers without using keyup function? Cos that's my main target. I want a jquery script dat will automatically generate the total without pressing any key or button..

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add two static values together automatically without entering any values into the textbox and display the total amount inside the third box, but it does not work.

Extract the ADD operation to a function, i.e: `compute()` and execute that function just after the DOM is fully loaded.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txt1, #txt2').keyup(compute);
  compute();
});

function compute() {
  var res = parseFloat($('#txt1').val()) || 0;
  var ser = parseFloat($('#txt2').val()) || 0;

  $('#total').val(res + ser);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <label>Text 1<span>*</span></label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control dec" id="txt1" name="txt1" value="30">

  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <label>Text 2<span>*</span></label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control dec" id="txt2" name="txt2" value="50">

  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <label>Total<span>*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" name="txt3">

  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks akasa, but what I want is, I want to get the total without keyup function.. Cos it's only display the total on keyup which I don't want..